Where to host database, wanting to create applications to manipulate data
I currently have a (relational) database in Access, however I wanted to create apps so I can search/change the data without looking at a ugly table.
I've been looking at Azure, specifically the Azure SQL Database, as a somewhere to host my database. The problems I've seen with Azure are:

Azure seems expensive (My database is ~6 tables, with the largest having around 45k records)
The learning curve for it seems steep

I exported the many tables to SharePoints lists (put them in a SharePoint site), so I could use PowerApps. This worked for a little bit, but I felt this was not how I should be storing my data (in SharePoint lists) and SharePoint/SharePoint lists felt restrictive.
Ultimately I would like somewhere to have my database where I can create mobile/web/desktop apps myself and others can use to view/manipulate the data in the database.

If you are using serverless database then it will be not as expensive. You can always go to the Azure pricing calculator and find the best fit for you. There are three main trade-off to be considered: scalability, controllability, and price.

Do you have any recommendations? I'm not familiar with databases, I'm not opposed to Azure however it seems very vast and complex.

I would recommend CosmosDB because you can use various kind of database within it.
